# Upload/Download files from iPhone over FTP protocol

Tags: ios, upload, ftp, download

I am trying to upload/download files between my iPhone and FTP server over FTP protocol (some of them are large), but I have no idea how to do this. Is there any way can do this?

Does ASIHttpRequest support FTP?

Or there are some other open source project can solve my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp

EDIT:
Actually i found this  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html

Comment: Thank you man. I am sorry for didn't  check your suggestion immediately. Thanks again.